# ELO credit card regular expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for the elo credit card which should allow only first 6 digits are mentioned below. The total length will be 16 and all 16 should be numbers only. Alphabets are not allow.

Allowed prefixes:

> 401178, 401179, 431274, 438935, 451416, 457393, 457631, 457632,
>   504175, 627780, 636297, 636368, 655000, 655001, 651652, 651653,
>   651654, 650485, 650486, 650487, 650488, 506699 to 506778 and  509000
>   to 509999

Comment: Have you ever used an alternation with regex before?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  nope

Comment: This is the RegExp that a friend that works at Elo gave me: /^((431274)|(438935)|(451416)|(457393)|(504175)|(627780)|(636297)|(636368)|(40117)[8-9]|(45763)[1-2]|(506)(699|7[1-7][1-8])|(509)[0-9][0-9][0-9]|(65003)[1-3]|(6500)(3[5-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-1])|(6504)(0[5-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9])|(650)(4(8[5-9]|9[0-9])|5([0-2][0-9]|3[0-8]))|(6505)(4[1-9]|[5-8][0-9]|9[0-8])|(6507)(0[0-9]|1[0-8])|(65072)[0-7]|(6509)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)|(6516)(5[2-9]|[6-7][0-9])|(6550)[0-1][0-9]|(6550)(2[1-9]|[3-4][0-9]|5[0-8]))/

Comment: You can validate for 16 digits: https://regex101.com/r/UdDyCX/1

Comment: @RicardoMartins Your pattern is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
^(?:40117[8-9]|431274|438935|451416|457393|45763[1-2]|504175
|627780|636297|636368|65500[0-1]|65165[2-4]|65048[5-8]|506699
|5067[0-6]\d|50677[0-8]|509\d{3})\d{10}$
```

> [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4Sq5R/3)

**Simple Explanation**

> 1. `^` Start of the line
> 2. `(` start of group
> 3. `?:` will not store it in the group
> 4. `40117[8-9]` means 40117 followed by anything between 8 to 9 ( same
>      applies for similars)
> 5. `|` means OR
> 6. `5067[0-6]\d` means 5067 + a digit between 0 to 6 + a single digit
>      (any)
> 7. `\d{10}` means it will see if the next 10 characters are digits (after previous valid 6 digits)
> 8. `$` end of the line

Answer (score 2):

Use an alternation, with a bit of extra work to cover the two numerical ranges you have.

```
^(?:401178|401179|431274|438935|451416|457393|457631|457632|504175|627780|636297|636368|
    655000|655001|651652|651653|651654|650485|650486|650487|650488|506699|5067[0-6][0-9]|
    50677[0-8]|509\d{3})\d{10}$
```

Here is how we handle the two ranges:

```
506699 to 506778

506699|            matches 506699
5067[0-6][0-9]|    matches 506700 through and including 506769
50677[0-8]         matches 506770 through and including 506778

509000 to 509999

509\d{3}           matches 509000 through and including 509999
                   i.e. 509 followed by any 3 digits
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Your Demo link doesn't cover all your samples!

Comment: thanks@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need alternation with some range operators to shorten the regex.

The most tricky part is to define the range `506699 to 506778`, which can be represented as `506699|5067[06]\d|50677[0-8]`.

```
(?x)^(?:
    40117[89]|431274|438935|451416|457393|457631|457632|504175
    |627780|636297|636368|65500[01]|65165[234]|65048[5-8]
    |506699|5067[06]\d|50677[0-8]
    |509\d{3}
)\d{10}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BbnHeQ/2

NB: the `(?x)` is used to allow for whitespace characters in the regex, which simplifies reading for log expressions.